# Adding multiple table rows into table layout using onClickListener dynamically

Tags: java, android

I'm using `onClickListener` to create a new table row in my table layout.
I've defined all the values to my table row and it's working fine though I would like to add multiple rows.

```
    final TableLayout tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tbl);
    final TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
    final TextView textview1 = new TextView(this);
    final TextView textview2 = new TextView(this);
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textview1.setText("B");
            textview1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkgrey);
            textview1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textview1.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
            textview2.setText("A");
            textview2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkgrey);
            textview2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textview2.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
            tr1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr1.addView(textview1);
            tr1.addView(textview2);
            tl.addView(tr1);
        }
    });
```

**XML**

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:id="@+id/tbl"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn">

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</TableLayout>
```

So I've clicked the button once and the new table row appears and after another click the app crashes.

How can I add multiple table rows into my table layout dynamically? I've thought using for loop, though I'm not sure about the right approach to apply it.

EDIT:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.none.myapplication, PID: 9775
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without the exact error message, but I feel it's because you create final variables and then try to add them a second time. Have you tried creating the new table row and text views inside the OnClickListener?

Using a for loop would not be useful in your case as you really want the row to be created when it's clicked.

Comment: You may look on the edit I have just made, it has error message there.

Comment: I just used another function to create row and it worked, thanks.